# JpaRepository getting Null at service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm new for Java Spring boot and I'm developing REST API by using JPA.
So, I want to access JpaRepository outside the `@RestController`. And I use `@Component` annotation top of the class header and use `@Autowired` annotation for declaring my repository instance.
But, repository instance always getting null.

---

**Application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class PriceHandlerServiceApplication
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run( PriceHandlerServiceApplication.class, args );
    }
}
```

---

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface ConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<ServiceConfiguration,Long>
{
}
```

---

**Model Class**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "service_configuration" )
@EntityListeners( AuditingEntityListener.class )
public class ServiceConfiguration
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty( "name" )
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty( "value" )
    private Double value;

    public ServiceConfiguration()
    {}
 }
```

---

**Service Class**

```
@Component
public class ConfigurationHandler
{
    @Autowired
    private static ConfigRepository configRepository;
    
    public static List<ServiceConfiguration> getAllConfigurations(){
        return configRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

---

And I call `ConfigurationHandler.getAllConfigurations()` by another class. But `configRepository` always getting null.

**[UPDATED]**
Remove static keyword but still not working. still `configRepository` repository getting null

```
@Component
public class ConfigurationHandler
{
    @Autowired
    private ConfigRepository configRepository;

    public ConfigurationHandler()
    { }

    public List<ServiceConfiguration> getAllConfigurations()
    {
        return configRepository.findAll();
    }
```

}

Comment: You cannot autowire static fields in Spring. Can you please try removing static and try?

Comment: @Govind If I removing static, then how I call 'getAllConfigurations()' method form another class. I want to access these instances from another class. Can I create new instance and call this method?

Comment: Show where you're using `ConfigurationHandler`. More generally, using constructor injection is better than field injection, and this kind of bug is a major reason why.

Comment: `List<ServiceConfiguration> list = new ConfigurationHandler().getAllConfigurations();` I used `ConfigurationHandler` like this.

Comment: There you are creating a new instance of ConfigurationHandler. You should use ConfigurationHandler from Spring context that will have configRepository autowired. Use @Autowired instance from an instance field or from constructor parameter.

Comment: @RikuJ.K.Sorry I can't understand what are you saying, because I'm a very new guy for spring boot. Can you add changes to `ConfigurationHandler` class

Comment: post the stacktrace with the exception details that you are facing.

Comment: @darkz `ConfigurationHandler` class looks good to me. The problem is where you are using it like this `List<ServiceConfiguration> list = new ConfigurationHandler().getAllConfigurations();`. You should use it like this `List<ServiceConfiguration> list = configurationHandler.getAllConfigurations();`, where `configurationHandler` is a instance field autowired by Spring.

Comment: @darkz, You can either autowire ConfigurationHandler class and invoke getAllConfigurations() method or autowire ConfigRepository class and invoke findAll () method into another classes.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks all. The problem was solved. previously, I used a new instance and that why getting null. After I autowire ConfigRepository and invoke findAll() method. Then no need to ConfigurationHandler class. Thanks all again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to check :

1. Remove the static keyword from `ConfigRepository` use it like :

   @Autowired
   private ConfigRepository configRepository;
2. Ensure that your repository interface and entity classes are under the main `Application.java` package or ensure that your Application.java is at the root of your package so that springboot auto configuration will automatically take up the repository , otherwise use the `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="your.package")`.
3. Ensure that the component class that you are trying to auto-wire the repository is actually managed by spring when you are using it. That is DO NOT use the `new` keyword if you want autowiring to work in your component class.
   So, when you want to use `ConfigurationHandler` use it like :

   @Autowire
   private ConfigurationHandler configurationHandler;

Comment: Thanks, @Ananthapadmanabhan.. The problem is I using a new instance for access methods.  .`@Autowired private ConfigurationHandler configurationHandler;` and `configurationHandler.getAllConfigurations()` working fine. Thanks again for support.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding, into `PriceHandlerServiceApplication` class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("repository.package")
```

also remove the static keyword

```
private static ConfigRepository configRepository;
```

Comment: I remove `static` keyword added public constructor. (I want to access this class from another class)  And also added `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation for `PriceHandlerServiceApplication`. But still not working. Still, repository getting null value.

Comment: sure, you can access using autowired in any class you want, did you replace "repository.package" by the package where you are putting your repositories?

Comment: yes, I added.. `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.assignment.priceHandlerService.repository")` but not working.

Comment: try it please, @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.assignment.priceHandlerService.repository")

Comment: @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.assignment.priceHandlerService.repository") this also tried. but still getting null value.